# How to specify a range in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, rspec-rails

I've been looking for a good way to see if a string of items are all numbers, and thought there might be a way of specifying a range from 0 to 9 and seeing if they're included in the string, but all that I've looked up online has really confused me.

```
def validate_pin(pin)
  (pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6) && pin.count("0-9") == pin.length
end
```

The code above is someone else's work and I've been trying to identify how it works. It's a pin checker - takes in a set of characters and ensures the string is either 4 or 6 digits and all numbers - but how does the range work?

When I did this problem I tried to use to_a? Integer and a bunch of other things including ranges such as (0..9) and ("0..9) and ("0".."9") to validate a character is an integer. When I saw ("0-9) it confused the heck out of me, and half an hour of googling and youtube has only left me with regex tutorials (which I'm interested in, but currently just trying to get the basics down)

So to sum this up, my goal is to understand a more semantic/concise way to identify if a character is an integer. Whatever is the simplest way. All and any feedback is welcome. I am a new rubyist and trying to get down my fundamentals. Thank You.

Comment: "....to see if a string of items are all numbers..." is not clear.  What about `"-24-12"`? I think you mean, "....to see if a string contains only the digits 0-9"`.

Comment: yes, that was really my goal to understand

Comment: @DavidVenegas : _ if a character is an integer_  : Do you really mean _a character_, or do you mean _ a String_? If you refer to strings, do you allow a prepending `-` to indicate negatives? If yes, do you allow spaces between the minus sign and the first digit? Please be a bit more specific in your question.

Comment: @user1934428 My question was supposed to be simple, but I got a bit carried away. Here's what I'm trying to understand. **Question:** By separating two numbers with a hyphen and surrounding them with quotes and parenthesis, do you get an array? I'm asking if ("0-9") is basically [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex really is the right way to do this. It's specifically for testing patterns in strings. This is how you'd test "do all characters in this string fall in the range of characters 0-9?":

```
pin.match(/\A[0-9]+\z/)
```

This regex says "Does this string start and end with at least one of the characters 0-9, with nothing else in between?" - the \A and \z are start-of-string and end-of-string matchers, and the `[0-9]+` matches any one or more of any character in that range.

You could even do your entire check in one line of regex:

```
pin.match(/\A([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6})\z/)
```

Which says "Does this string consist of the characters 0-9 repeated exactly 4 times, or the characters 0-9, repeated exactly 6 times?"

Ruby's [String#count method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-count) does something similar to this, though it just counts the number of occurrences of the characters passed, and it uses something similar to regex ranges to allow you to specify character ranges.

> The sequence c1-c2 means all characters between c1 and c2.

Thus, it expands the parameter "0-9" into the list of characters "0123456789", and then it tests how many of the characters in the string match that list of characters.

This will work to verify that a certain number of numbers exist in the string, and the length checks let you implicitly test that no *other* characters exist in the string. However, regexes let you assert that directly, by ensuring that the whole string matches a given pattern, including length constraints.

Comment: This is the right answer but do you mind explaining if the method `pin.count("0-9")` would work?

Comment: I second @Mohammad, does pin.count("0-9") work by itself

Comment: See the linked documentation for String#count.

Comment: A tiny point, so tiny I'm not sure if it deserves mention, but here it is: you may want to use a non-capture (rather than capture) group. Whenever I see a regex with a capture group I'm expecting the content of the capture group to be referenced later. When, as here, I find that content is not referenced I realized that I've just lost hundreds of milliseconds of my time thinking about it. That's enough to ruin one's day.

Answer (score 2):

Count everything non-digit in `pin` and check if this count is zero:

```
pin.count("^0-9").zero?
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be looking for answers outside regex and since Chris already spelled out how the count method was being implemented in the example above, I'll try to add one more idea for testing whether a string is an Integer or not:

```
pin.to_i.to_s == pin
```

What we're doing is converting the string to an integer, converting that result back to a string, and then testing to see if anything changed during the process.  If the result is `=>true`, then you know nothing changed during the conversion to an integer and therefore the string is only an Integer.

EDIT:
The example above only works if the entire string is an Integer and won’t properly deal with leading zeros.  If you want to check to make sure each and every character is an Integer then do something like this instead:

```
pin.prepend(“1”).to_i.to_s(1..-1) == pin
```

Comment: This is pretty creative, although probably not best practice(gotta learn regex) thank you Micheal

Comment: I agree that using regular expressions might be the most logical solution since they’re explicitly stating their purpose and being used exactly as intended.  My solution on the other hand doesn’t offer many clues as to what it’s purpose is.  Bear in mind though that regular expressions are generally considered much slower computationally speaking so using them isn’t all roses.  I personally find them extremely difficult to read too which I PERSONALLY think is worth considering depending on the application.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the question seems to be exactly HOW the following portion of code is doing its job:

```
pin.count("0-9")
```

This piece of the code is simply returning a count of how many instances of the numbers 0 through 9 exist in the string.  That's only one piece of the relevant section of code though.   You need to look at the rest of the line to make sense of it:

```
pin.count("0-9") == pin.length
```

The first part counts how many instances then the second part compares that to the length of the string.  If they are equal (`==`) then that means every character in the string is an Integer.

Comment: Yes thank you for clarifying that, but the real question I had was if ("0-9") was an array. I thought it was like a string and I couldn't ask my .count enumerable to count it. Is ("0-9") and array?

Comment: “0-9” is neither a string nor an array.  It’s a parameter list (a bit like an argument).

Comment: Read more here:  https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-count

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes negation can be used to advantage:

```
!pin.match?(/\D/) && [4,6].include?(pin.length)
```

`pin.match?(/\D/)` returns `true` if the string contains a character other than a digit (matching `/\D/`), in which case it it would be negated to `false`.

One advantage of using negation here is that if the string contains a character other than a digit `pin.match?(/\D/)` would return `true` as soon as a non-digit is found, as opposed to methods that examine all the characters in the string.